# Why is my while loop making python crash?

Tags: python, cs50, minimax

I'm doing cs50 AI first problem: tic tac toe and the minimax algorithm (at the bottom of the file). I've tried and explain in the code comments what I'm trying to do.
I do not get any error messages, python simply crashes. I get the mac spinning wheel and "python 3.7.6 not responding" when I force-quit.

line 140, `lst.append([score, (i,j)])` , I have a doubt which (i,j) gets appended to the list. I want to add each possible move and its value from the initial set of possible moves. I'm afraid I'm adding the final move of each possible game.

Can anyone confirm this is what is happening?
How can I fix this?
Why is python crashing?

Thanks a lot

```
X = "X"
O = "O"
EMPTY = None
lst = []


def initial_state():
    """
    Returns starting state of the board.
    """
    return [[EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY],
            [EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY],
            [EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY]]


def player(board):
    """
    Returns player who has the next turn on a board.
    """
   # if number of filled boxes is odd : O's move
   # if                           even: X's
    ct = 0
    for i in range(len(board)):
        for j in range(len(board[1])):
            if board[i][j] != None:
                ct += 1
    if ct % 2 == 0:
        return X
    else:
        return O



def actions(board):
    """
    Returns set of all possible actions (i, j) available on the board.
    """
    poss_actions = set()
    for i in range(len(board)):
        for j in range(len(board[1])):
            if board [i][j] == None:
                poss_actions.add((i,j))
    return poss_actions



def result(board, action):
    """
    Returns the board that results from making move (i, j) on the board.
    """
    i = action[0]
    j = action[1]
    if board[i][j] != None:
        raise Exception ('Illegal move!')
    board[i][j] = player(board)
    return board 



def winner(board):
    """
    Returns the winner of the game, if there is one.
    """
    if board[0][0] == O and (board[0][1] == O and board [0][2] == O) or (board[1][0] == O and board[2][0] == O) or (board[1][1] == O  and board[2][2] == O):
        return O
    elif board [1][1] == O and (board[1][0] == O and board[1][2] == O) or (board[0][1] == O and board[2][1] == O) or (board[0][2] == O and board[2][0] == O):
        return O
    elif board[2][2] == O and (board[2][0] == O and board[2][1] == O) or (board[0][2] == O and board[1][2] == O):
        return O
    elif board[0][0] == X and (board[0][1] == X and board [0][2] == X) or (board[1][0] == X and board[2][0] == X) or (board[1][1] == X  and board[2][2] == X):
       return X
    elif board [1][1] == X and (board[1][0] == X and board[1][2] == X) or (board[0][1] == X and board[2][1] == X) or (board[1][1] == X and board[2][0] == X):
        return X
    elif board[2][2] == X and (board[2][0] == X and board[2][1] == X) or (board[0][2] == X and board[1][2] == X):
        return X
    else:
        return None
    


def terminal(board):
    """
    Returns True if game is over, False otherwise.
    """
    ct = 0
    for i in range(len(board)):
        for j in range(len(board)):
            if board[i][j] == None:
                ct += 1
    if winner(board) == X or winner(board) == O:
        return True
    elif ct == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False


def utility(board):
    """
    Returns 1 if X has won the game, -1 if O has won, 0 otherwise.
    """
    if winner(board) == X:
        return 1
    elif winner(board) == O:
        return -1
    else:
        return 0


def minimax(board):
    """
    Returns the optimal action for the current player on the board.
    """
    # I created a list to store the value of ll the possible moves
    # as a global variable so it doesn't get initialise when the function is called recursively

    # <actions(board)> returns a set of tuples (i,j) corresponding to the coordinates of possible moves
    for i,j in actions(board):
        while terminal(board) == False: # for as long as the game is not over
            # <player(board)> determines whose turn it is
            # the <if> condition should make every other iteration play the best move for X or for O
            if player(board) == X:
                board[i][j] = X
                minimax(board)
            else: 
                board[i][j] = O
                minimax(board)
            # if this is doing what I hope it is doing, there is necessary a point where the game is over
            # and we get out of the <while> loop
        score = utility(board)    # this is eiher 1, 0 or -1    
        lst.append([score, (i,j)]) # list of list that keeps together each possible move and its value (but there is probably a problem)
        board[i][j] = None # cancel the move so we can calculate another in the <for loop
    if player(board) == X:
        return max(lst)[1]
    else:
        return min(lst)[1]
```

The functions are called by runner.py:

```
import pygame
import sys
import time

import tictactoe as ttt

pygame.init()
size = width, height = 600, 400

# Colors
black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

mediumFont = pygame.font.Font("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", 28)
largeFont = pygame.font.Font("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", 40)
moveFont = pygame.font.Font("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", 60)

user = None
board = ttt.initial_state()
ai_turn = False

while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

    screen.fill(black)

    # Let user choose a player.
    if user is None:

        # Draw title
        title = largeFont.render("Play Tic-Tac-Toe", True, white)
        titleRect = title.get_rect()
        titleRect.center = ((width / 2), 50)
        screen.blit(title, titleRect)

        # Draw buttons
        playXButton = pygame.Rect((width / 8), (height / 2), width / 4, 50)
        playX = mediumFont.render("Play as X", True, black)
        playXRect = playX.get_rect()
        playXRect.center = playXButton.center
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, playXButton)
        screen.blit(playX, playXRect)

        playOButton = pygame.Rect(5 * (width / 8), (height / 2), width / 4, 50)
        playO = mediumFont.render("Play as O", True, black)
        playORect = playO.get_rect()
        playORect.center = playOButton.center
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, playOButton)
        screen.blit(playO, playORect)

        # Check if button is clicked
        click, _, _ = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
        if click == 1:
            mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            if playXButton.collidepoint(mouse):
                time.sleep(0.2)
                user = ttt.X
            elif playOButton.collidepoint(mouse):
                time.sleep(0.2)
                user = ttt.O

    else:

        # Draw game board
        tile_size = 80
        tile_origin = (width / 2 - (1.5 * tile_size),
                       height / 2 - (1.5 * tile_size))
        tiles = []
        for i in range(3):
            row = []
            for j in range(3):
                rect = pygame.Rect(
                    tile_origin[0] + j * tile_size,
                    tile_origin[1] + i * tile_size,
                    tile_size, tile_size
                )
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, rect, 3)

                if board[i][j] != ttt.EMPTY:
                    move = moveFont.render(board[i][j], True, white)
                    moveRect = move.get_rect()
                    moveRect.center = rect.center
                    screen.blit(move, moveRect)
                row.append(rect)
            tiles.append(row)

        game_over = ttt.terminal(board)
        player = ttt.player(board)

        # Show title
        if game_over:
            winner = ttt.winner(board)
            if winner is None:
                title = f"Game Over: Tie."
            else:
                title = f"Game Over: {winner} wins."
        elif user == player:
            title = f"Play as {user}"
        else:
            title = f"Computer thinking..."
        title = largeFont.render(title, True, white)
        titleRect = title.get_rect()
        titleRect.center = ((width / 2), 30)
        screen.blit(title, titleRect)

        # Check for AI move
        if user != player and not game_over:
            if ai_turn:
                time.sleep(0.5)
                move = ttt.minimax(board)
                board = ttt.result(board, move)
                ai_turn = False
            else:
                ai_turn = True

        # Check for a user move
        click, _, _ = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
        if click == 1 and user == player and not game_over:
            mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            for i in range(3):
                for j in range(3):
                    if (board[i][j] == ttt.EMPTY and tiles[i][j].collidepoint(mouse)):
                        board = ttt.result(board, (i, j))

        if game_over:
            againButton = pygame.Rect(width / 3, height - 65, width / 3, 50)
            again = mediumFont.render("Play Again", True, black)
            againRect = again.get_rect()
            againRect.center = againButton.center
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, againButton)
            screen.blit(again, againRect)
            click, _, _ = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
            if click == 1:
                mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                if againButton.collidepoint(mouse):
                    time.sleep(0.2)
                    user = None
                    board = ttt.initial_state()
                    ai_turn = False

    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: Yo do not show how you call this ... your minmax just fills in X and O in _the same_ order of the generated possible moves ([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]] only for None cells). Withpout knowing how to call it its futile to search the error. Beside that there are several optimizations on the shown code that come to mind. Please [edit].

Comment: Hi Patrick. I add the file that runs the functions.

Comment: It is not crashing. If it did that, it will exit with an exception. It is doing what you instructed it to do.

Comment: where is the connection between your GUI and the minmax? Your minmax never explores all possible moves for X/O until a game is won .- it only applies X and O to the leftover moves in order. Your minmax would need to explore the "possible" moves for ANY placement X can do and all placements O can do. You then breadth/depth search for the one thing that suits you - respectively either X or O wins (whatever the non player is) and then use that move. If placing X on _that_ field lieads to 3 wins for X and plaxing X on any other field gives you 2 or less wins for X then you choose the 3-field move.

Comment: You also pass along the board (a list) and modify it - so it is full after one simulation - you would need to copy the board and simulate on the board copies...